# Failed to insert data to Postgresql Constraint CHECK

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have tried to insert data on the table as following

```
CREATE TABLE account.companies
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('account.companies_id_seq'::regclass),
    account_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('account.companies_account_id_seq'::regclass),
    status character varying(12) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    account_type character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT companies_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT companies_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
        REFERENCES account.accounts (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT status_check CHECK (status::text = 'SUBMITTED'::text OR status::text = 'PENDING'::text OR status::text = 'ACTION_REQ'::text OR status::text = 'PASS'::text OR status::text = 'FAIL'::text),
    CONSTRAINT account_type_check CHECK (status::text = 'INDIVIDUAL'::text OR status::text = 'COMPANY'::text)
)
```

insert records from pgadmin4 and error

Should be able to insert data

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the `INSERT` statement you used ([edit] your question, do **not** post code in comments) and the exact error message you get. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer ..it was taken from old file
the new file already corrected

```
CONSTRAINT account_type_check CHECK (account_type::text = 'INDIVIDUAL'::text OR account_type::text = 'COMPANY'::text)
```

)